# Proving that $ \mid z+1\mid^{2}=2\mid z\mid^{2} \Leftrightarrow \mid z-1\mid^{2}=2 $

Tags: complex-numbers

Let z be a complex number.
How does one prove, using the properties of the conjugate and the modulus, that:

$$ \mid z+1\mid^{2}=2\mid z\mid^{2}
\Leftrightarrow
\mid z-1\mid^{2}=2 $$

Comment: More generally, for every complex numbers $(u,v)$, $$|z+u|^2=2|z+v|^2\iff|z+2v-u|^2=2|u-v|^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two esential properties that you have to use are $\overline{w_1 + w_2} = \overline{w_1} + \overline{w_2}$ and ${|w|}^2 = w \overline{w}$ for each $w , w_1 , w_2 \in \mathbb{C}$.

Fix $z \in \mathbb{C}$. With these two properties, you should see that (as $z + \overline{z} = 2 Re z$)
$$
{|z + 1|}^2 = {|z|}^2 + 2 (Re z) + 1 \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad {|z - 1|}^2 = {|z|}^2 - 2 (Re z) + 1\mbox{.}
$$
Thus,
$$
{|z + 1|}^2 = 2 {|z|}^2 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad {|z|}^2 = 2 (Re z) + 1 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad {|z - 1|}^2 = 2\mbox{.}
$$

Comment: wow! to me, that is very farfetched. did you see it because you are used to working with these numbers or is there a trick to it?

Comment: It is enough to have done a complex analysis course.

Comment: @JocaPinto I think that the person answering was just deliberately not tryng to give you all of the details so that you still have to do some of the work on your own. You don't have to know off hand that $|z+ 1|^2 = |z|^2 + 2\operatorname{Re}(z) + 1$, because it follows easily from using the properties mentioned in the first line of the answer.

Comment: @Dylan i got that, and it was fairly simple to understand it. the thing is, i'm pretty sure i would've not gotten there by myself if i kept trying. maybe it's just because i'm very new on the complex numbers subject

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use (three times) the fact that $|z|^2=z.\overline z$.

Answer (score 0):

An elementary solution:

First, note that $|x+iy|^2=x^2+y^2,|x+1+iy|^2=x^2+2x+1+y^2$, and $|z-1  |^2=(x-1)^2+y^2.$

We have then
$$ x^2+2x+1+y^2=2x^2+2y^2$$
or $$x^2-2x+1-2+y^2=0$$

which is equivalent with the following

$$(x-1)^2+y^2=2$$

and again, this is what we needed

$$|z-1  |^2=2.$$